# Turning off iOS backswipe

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

Is possible to turn off the backswipe for certain part of the screen? In particular, I was thinking of using this method:

```
func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer!) -> Bool {
    return false;
}
```

I was thinking to recognize what part of the screen the user has pressed on, if it is within a certain interval, I would return true, else false. Not sure how to pickup where the user has pressed.

Comment: within a certain interval what do you mean ?

Comment: I mean a location interval, like 2D coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the functionality provided by the UINavigationController.

First your class should conform to the UIGestureRecognizerProtocol something like this:

```
class MyController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerProtocol
```

Then you need to register to become the delegate for the navigation controller so probably in your viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear (depending on needs) you have this:

```
self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
```

Then you can use the following to check where in the view the gesture start:

```
func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    let location = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.view)
    if location.y > 500 {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Obviously this is just a test case where it ignores the gesture when it starts above 500 in the vertical and you can change that to whatever you want.

Comment: Excellent! Only change needed was UIGestureRecognizerDelegate. Was UIGestureRecognizerProtocol depreciated at some point?

Comment: No sorry that was my mistake it should be `UIGestureRegonizerDelegate` but it is a protocol.  I just typed the wrong thing.